# inner join, SQL, 4 tables

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net

I know there are tools available to rectify this, but somehow i cannot make out the mistake(s) that disallowed the retrieval of records, despite 2 hours of trying and referencing.

Can anyone help me with this? Im using VS 2008 btw.

```
SELECT pc.product_category_id, pc.product_category_name,
       pi.product_image_id, pi.product_image_filename, 
       qr.qrcode_id, qr.qrcode_code, *
FROM Product AS p
INNER JOIN ProductCategory AS pc ON p.product_category_id = pc.product_category_id
INNER JOIN ProductImage AS pi ON p.product_image_id = pi.product_image_id
INNER JOIN  QRCode AS qr ON p.qrcode_id = qr.qrcode_id
WHERE p.product_id = '" & DropDownList2.Text & "'"
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or something?

Comment: As Darin said, add some information to your question that would actually allow someone to help you.

Comment: My guess would be your error is produced by not explicitly referencing, which table `*` comes from. it should by, e.g. `p.*`. As a side-note using `*` can cause problems in the future if you need to do anything to your tables. It's normally better to explicitly reference the columns you need.

Comment: @Ben - Without specifying the table, it means all tables, this is not a source of error.

Comment: @Dems, if no columns were explicitly referenced then yes, but with referenced columns you normally need to specify which table everything comes from. Even if I'm wrong ( quite possible! ) the advice still stands about not using `*`...

Comment: @Ben - With or without referencing other columns, `*` will still work, not yield an error nor cause 0 records to be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, manually check that the record you want to acquire and join exists...

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE product_id = <insert a value here by hand>

SELECT * FROM ProductCategory WHERE product_category_id = <value from the first SELECT>

SELECT * FROM ProductImage WHERE product_image_id = <value from the first SELECT>

SELECT * FROM QRCode WHERE qrcode_id = <value from the first SELECT>
```

If you get records for all of these, than you can be sure your joins are working.  If not, are you missing records, or need to use LEFT JOINs?

So your next check should be that you're passing the correct value to your SQL query...

```
myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT '" & DropDownList2.Text & "'"
```

Are you also sure that you need `'` around the ID?  this indicates strings, and IDs are more *normally* integers.

Finally, look at parameterised queries, rather than building up the string manually.

Comment: thank you, actually i tested out both p.* & listing out all column names explicitly. Somehow the records dont show as there were no records in 1 of the table, so when i put it sample ones, it just worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query will only return products that have a category, an image, and a qrcode because of the inner joins. If these columns can be null in the product table, you must use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (often simply written as `LEFT JOIN`). In addition, you should use `p.*`, not just `*`, since this would return all available columns. There is no point in returning the ids like `pc.product_category_id`, since the same value is already returned from 'p.*'.

```
SELECT
    p.*,
    pc.product_category_name,
    pi.product_image_filename,
    qr.qrcode_code
FROM
    Product AS p
    LEFT JOIN ProductCategory AS pc
        ON p.product_category_id = pc.product_category_id
    LEFT JOIN ProductImage AS pi
        ON p.product_image_id = pi.product_image_id
    LEFT JOIN QRCode AS qr
        ON p.qrcode_id = qr.qrcode_id
WHERE
    p.product_id = 'xxx'
```